# IF and AND in combination

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have problems with the IF function. I want to combine the AND function with it. What I did was:

```
If(and((C2:G2)>5,5);"Gehaald";"Niet gehaald")
```

I know you can do it all manually this way:

```
And(C2>5,5;D2>5,5...)
```

Is there any way to write this formula shorter?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you might be looking for is:

```
=IF(MIN(C2:G2)>5,5;"Gehaald";"Niet gehaald")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I would have never thought of that!